# Connection time out - port 4444 (java Application)

Tags: java, port, chatroom, blocked

I am working for my network class at a chatroom application, in java, and i have encountered some issues with the connection.

The main problem is that I can connect my client to the server, however when I'm trying to use my external ip is not working.So i browsed the web and i found that I have to port forward from my router in order to accept the connection from an external ip. I've done that, but I didn't work.

After I searched for an answer I found that the connection somehow is blocked, probably, by a firewall(in my case I have the windows firewall, my av firewall- COMODO IS, and my router's firewall).I disable all of them, in normal mode, but same result.

The last thing that I've tried was to boot in safe mode and it worked.Now my question is:
Is there some third party software that cause this, my firewall from the COMODO can be the problem or something else?

I'm using :

- Windows 7 Professional SP1
- ASUS Router RT-N53
- COMODO AV 2013 Internet
  Security

As for the connection I'm using port 4444 and my IP address is dynamic.

Thank you for any help you can provide in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn's out to be COMODO's firewall that caused this.I've read that, even tough you'll close the antivirus it's not enough to allow access of a specific port to access it.Now that I've removed it the issue has been solved.

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

For this your server should be at public/static IP address. As routers are NAT based. It requests as its own and forward after it, if you are using LAN, After router it use Class C sub-masking which is 192.168.1.1

So server should be Out of this network. if u turn on server inside this network, It should be accessible with in. 192.*.*.*

Comment: I've noticed something else, that might be a clue.At school when i was connected to one of faculty's wireless connection, working inside the network i had the same problem.And also in linux (Ubunu 14.04) i tested with a friend from a different network and i was able to connect.

Comment: is it the same domain? and also verify faculty's systems is not using proxy ip